'SignedTransaction' object has no attribute 'rawTransaction'
`
from web3 import Web3
import os
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Define RPC URLs for different networks
RPC_URLS = {
    "ethereum": os.getenv("ETHEREUM_RPC_URL", f"https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/{os.getenv('ALCHEMY_API_KEY')}"),
    "polygon": os.getenv("POLYGON_RPC_URL", "https://polygon-rpc.com"),
    "base": os.getenv("BASE_RPC_URL", "https://mainnet.base.org")
}

# Wallet details
SOURCE_PRIVATE_KEY = os.getenv("SOURCE_PRIVATE_KEY")
SOURCE_ADDRESS = Web3.to_checksum_address(os.getenv("SOURCE_ADDRESS"))
DESTINATION_ADDRESS = Web3.to_checksum_address(os.getenv("DESTINATION_ADDRESS"))

# Forwarding function for all networks
def forward_eth(network, rpc_url):
    """Send ETH from the source wallet to the destination on a specific network."""
    try:
        # Connect to the Web3 provider for the current network
        web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc_url))

        # Get the balance of the source wallet in wei
        balance = web3.eth.get_balance(SOURCE_ADDRESS)

        # Debugging: Print balance for the current network
        print(f"{network.capitalize()} Network:")
        print(f"Wallet Balance (Wei): {balance}")
        print(f"Wallet Balance (Ether): {web3.from_wei(balance, 'ether')}")
        
        # Estimate gas
        gas_price = web3.eth.gas_price
        gas_limit = 21000  # Standard gas limit for ETH transfer
        total_gas_cost = gas_price * gas_limit
        
        # Debugging: Print gas calculation
        print(f"Gas Price (Wei): {gas_price}")
        print(f"Gas Limit: {gas_limit}")
        print(f"Total Gas Cost (Wei): {total_gas_cost}")
        
        # Calculate the amount to send, excluding gas fees
        amount_to_send = balance - total_gas_cost

        # If you want to send all ETH, including gas fees, use this:
        # amount_to_send = balance

        # Prepare transaction if the balance is enough
        if amount_to_send > 0:
            nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(SOURCE_ADDRESS)
            tx = {
                'nonce': nonce,
                'to': DESTINATION_ADDRESS,
                'value': amount_to_send,
                'gas': gas_limit,
                'gasPrice': gas_price
            }

            # Sign the transaction
            signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=SOURCE_PRIVATE_KEY)
            
            # Send the transaction
            tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx["rawTransaction"])  # Correct access in v6+
            print(f"Transaction sent! Hash: {web3.toHex(tx_hash)}\n")
        else:
            print(f"Insufficient balance to cover gas fees on {network}.\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error with {network}: {e}\n")

# Main function to check all networks and forward ETH
def forward_eth_across_all_networks():
    print("Starting ETH forwarding bot across all networks...\n")
    
    # List of networks to check
    networks = ["ethereum", "polygon", "base"]
    for network in networks:
        # Get the RPC URL for the current network
        rpc_url = RPC_URLS.get(network)

        # Call the forwarding function for the current network
        forward_eth(network, rpc_url)

def main():
    while True:
        forward_eth_across_all_networks()
        time.sleep(30)  # Check every 30 seconds for all networks

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

` trying to make an eth forwarding bot and keep getting this issue and have no idea on how to fix.
First post on here mb if i did it wrong, just trying to fix an annoying problem. The point of this code is to be a bot that, whenever eth is sent to my alt wallet, this bot automatically sends it to my main wallet, it calculates for gas fees and what not too
this is what it returns, not really an error but something that went wrong somewhere

Please provide more details on what your are trying to achieve. Also, please edit your question to include your code and the error you are getting as text, rather than screenshots.

Put a breakpoint in your code and use dir(signed_tx) and print(signed_tx) to see what attributes and members there are available

What version of web3.py/eth_account are you using? It looks like you're using web3 >= v6.0.0 where deprecated camelCase methods were removed in favor of snake_case ones while your code has been written for <v6.0.0.
In this case, 2 solutions:

use an older web3 version (ex v5.28), make sure dependencies like eth_account are also downgraded.
or update your code with the corresponding snake_case methods and attributes (ex raw_transaction i/o rawTransaction).

